# Ruby map to append dot at the end

Tags: ruby, string, loops, string-concatenation

I have the below line

```
new_records = records.map{|record| record.name.to_s.}.sort
```

which outputs

```
# Current Output:

new_records = ["ab-12.cd.net", "de-34.fg.net"]
```

How can I make it to return with a `.` (dot) at the end?

```
# Desired Output:

new_records = ["ab-12.cd.net.", "de-34.fg.net."]
```

I can do it using another map, for example

```
new_records = records.map{|record| record.name.to_s.}.sort
new_records2 = new_records.map { |record| "#{record}." }
```

But looking for an efficient way of achieving it using the 1st map itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would work:

```
new_records = records.map{|record| "#{record.name.to_s}." }.sort
```

you can also use `+` like this:

```
new_records = records.map{|record| record.name.to_s + "." }.sort
```

Comment: I would recommend explaining the difference between ' and " and when to use each, since you're already giving an example of both types of string concatenation.

Comment: @anothermh feel free to edit answer with an explanation